# Disable / Deregister all JS from all plugins

Tags: plugins, javascript

How can i disable all js files from plugins and load one single js file which i have combined and compressed ?

Is there any way ?

Answer (score 1):

You could install a plug-in like [asset Queue Manager](https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/asset-queue-manager/) to keep track of all the active stylesheets and javascript files (it's preaty neat, you can live-preview how the page would look without an asset to see if your site gets broken or not), and then in your theme's `functions.php` file, put a code like the following

```
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'my_deregister_javascript', 100 );
function my_deregister_javascript() {
  $deregistered_scripts=array('wc-add-to-cart',
    'woocommerce',
    'storefront-skip-link-focus-fix',
    'wc-add-to-cart-variation',
    'wc-cart-fragments',
    'storefront-navigation',
    'wc-single-product');
  foreach ($deregistered_scripts as $key => $script) {
    wp_deregister_script( $script );
  }
}
```

(of course you may want to replace the `$deregistered_scripts` array with only the ones that you won't be using)

If your blog is in development mode and you find an error message after this, some plug-in might be causing the issue. Try adding an @ to the line 250 of `/wp-includes/class.wp-scripts.php` (it worked for me to solve an error warning woocommerce was throwing)

```
public function set_group( $handle, $recursion, $group = false ) {
        if ( @$this->registered[$handle]->args === 1 ) //"@" added
            $grp = 1;
        else
            $grp = (int) $this->get_data( $handle, 'group' );

        if ( false !== $group && $grp > $group )
            $grp = $group;

        return parent::set_group( $handle, $recursion, $grp );
    }
```

**Edit**: the deregistering-scripts code was addapted from [this blog article by Justin Tadlock](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/08/06/how-to-disable-scripts-and-styles)

Comment: Been using asset queue manager for a few months now... Very useful. Just came across a [similar one that is also awesome](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-asset-clean-up/), with the advantage of letting you dequeue scripts on individual pages/posts.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the first answer, but this should work

```
function remove_all_scripts() {
   foreach( wp_scripts()->registered as $script ) {
      wp_dequeue_script( $script );
      wp_deregister_script( $script );
  }
} 
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_all_scripts', PHP_INT_MAX);
```

Comment: You should dequeue and deregister to completely remove scripts and styles. Also, your priority should also be correct, probably a priority like `PHP_INT_MAX` will be useful here

Comment: I'm not sure if the `wp_script_is` part is neessary... what do you think Pieter? Also, using `PHP_INT_MAX` is a great idea. I never have thought to do that before. Is there any downsides to using that ever?

Comment: *I'm not sure if the `wp_script_is` part is neessary* No, not necessary, `wp_script_is()` is useful if you need to check if a script already exists and is currently registered/enqueued/etc to avoid conflict when you add your own scripts. As for `PHP_INT_MAX`, it is useful to make sure that your action runs dead last, specially when you need to remove like in this case

Comment: Ok cool so it's ok to dequeue a script if it hasn't been enqueued?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do something like this:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse8170_disable_all_scripts', 9999 );
function wpse8170_disable_all_scripts() {
    global $wp_scripts, $wp_styles;

    $wp_styles = new WP_Styles(); // reset all styles
    $wp_scripts = new WP_Scripts(); // reset all scripts
}
```

But pay attention that this is bad habit to do what you want to do and could lead to **unexpected** results in the future.

Comment: will this also disable wordpress core js files from wp-includes

Comment: i just want to disable all js and css from plugins and theme files

Comment: yes, it has to clear all already enqueued scripts and styles

Comment: This does keep the core scripts/styles - however it will not remove anything registered (or enqueued directly) after `wp_enqueue_scripts`.